# В чем разница между установщиками до Qt_5.8 и после?

Tags: qt

В чём разница между установщиками qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.8.0.exe и qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.5.exe ?

Раньше я работал на Qt_4.8, там был стандартный установщик. *qt_(тип программного обеспечения) _ (поддерживаемая операционная система) _ (разрядность) _ (нужный тип используемого компилятора) _ (разрядность системы) _ (версия программного продукта).exe*

Как я понял так было до версии 5.8.0, после всё стало иначе.

И  мне вообще не понятно (на примере 5.9.5):

- почему на виндувс три версии при этом две из них это зипы?
- Что означает pdb?
- В чём разница между uwp и desktop?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Что означает pdb?

Это так называемые *файлы отладочных символов*. В них хранится соответствие участков машинного кода строкам исходного кода и регистров/участков памяти/смещений на стеке исходным переменным.

> почему на виндувс три версии при этом две из них это зипы?

Потому что первые два файла — это не сам Qt, а наборы этих самых `.pdb`-файлов. Как правило, пошаговый проход внутри Qt-ных библиотек не нужен, поэтому их убрали из основного установочного файла. Ещё, количество этих файлов достаточно мало, поэтому для них не стали оформлять отдельный установочный пакет.

> В чём разница между uwp и desktop?

UWP — это фишка Windows 10, приложения на .NET, которые распространяются через магазин приложений и могут быть без изменений запущены хоть на компьютере, хоть на смартфоне (Windows Phone,  благодаря единому API). Этакий аналог Desktop+Mobile+Android Java, положенного на Linux-овые репозитории.

Ну а Windows-приложения — это обычные PE EXE файлы, которые существовали, начиная с Windows 2000. *Наверное, сюда же можно отнести и NE EXE из Windows <=95, но это уже другой вопрос.*